# angular ui-router $stateParams in json string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using $stateParams to successfully get a dynamic id, but I haven't been successful in get the param value to work within my json data string.

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, resolveJson, $stateParams) {
  //This verifies that the id value works
  $scope.pageid = $stateParams.id;

  //This doesn't work
  $scope.data = resolveJson.data.$stateParams.id;

  //This also doesn't work
  $scope.data = resolveJson.data.pageid;

  //This does work, but it's now not dynamic
  $scope.data = resolveJson.data.7;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.data = resolveJson.data[$stateParams.id];
```

`resolveJson.data.$stateParams` doesn't have a `$stateParams` parameter, which is what it is looking for.  By using `[]`'s instead of dot notation, it will look for the parameter with the name of whatever `$stateParams.id` contains.